# How can create counts of terms in a one column and abend the counts as additional coulmns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a panda data frame that looks like this:

```
ID   Key
101  A
102  A
205  A
101  B
105  A
605  A
200  A
102  B
```

I would like to make a new table that counts the number of occurrences of "A" and "B" in the Key column and make them as new two headers. The table would then look like this:

```
ID  A  B 
101 1  1
102 1  1
205 1  0
105 1  0
605 1  0
200 1  0
```

I have treid groubing by 'ID' and  'Key' and get the sizes as here:

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'Key']).size().transform('A', 'B')
```

But it says the series doesn't have the attribute 'transform', and actually, I am not even sure if I can have two arguments passed to 'transform'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['ID', 'Key']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
Key  A  B
ID       
101  1  1
102  1  1
105  1  0
200  1  0
205  1  0
605  1  0
```

Or [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['ID'], df['Key'])
print (df)
Key  A  B
ID       
101  1  1
102  1  1
105  1  0
200  1  0
205  1  0
605  1  0
```