# Sum of specific rows based on boolean indicator and return the results in new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
DF = 
 ID  Shop  Sales  Ind 
 1   A     554    T
 2   B     678    F
 3   A     546    T
 4   A     896    T
 5   B     426    F
 6   B     391    T
 7   C     998    F
 8   C     565    T
 9   C     128    T
```

I am trying to sum for each ID the sales of each shop so that I have them in separate columns as below (where x is the sum ). The values to be summed should only be the ones matching the True values in the `Ind`variable

```
DF2 = 
 ID  Shop  Sales  Ind   A_Sum    B_Sum   C_Sum
 1     A     554    T     x       0       0
 2     B     678    F     0       x       0
 3     A     546    T     x       0       0
 4     A     896    T     x       0       0
 5     B     426    F     0       x       0
 6     B     391    T     0       x       0
 7     C     998    F     0       0       x
 8     C     565    T     0       0       x
 9     C     128    T     0       0       x
```

I tried this, but I am far from being right! I am stick at how to encode the boolean index at the sum operation? and also at automatically naming the columns

```
DF2 = DF.groupby(['ID', 'Shop'])['Sales'].transform('sum')
```

Any help on this?

Comment: try `df.groupby(['ID', 'Shop'])['Sales'].agg(['sum'])`

Comment: You can see my answer, also you previous question can explain this too :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197374/how-can-create-counts-of-terms-in-a-one-column-and-abend-the-counts-as-additiona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your effort

```
DF['SUM']=DF.groupby(['ID', 'Shop'])['Sales'].transform('sum')
DF.loc[DF.Ind == 'F', 'SUM'] = 0
pd.concat([DF,DF.pivot(columns='Shop',values='SUM').
          add_suffix('_Sum').fillna(0)],axis=1).drop(['SUM'],axis=1)

Out[247]: 
   ID Shop  Sales Ind  A_Sum  B_Sum  C_Sum
0   1    A    554   T  554.0    0.0    0.0
1   2    B    678   F    0.0    0.0    0.0
2   3    A    546   T  546.0    0.0    0.0
3   4    A    896   T  896.0    0.0    0.0
4   5    B    426   F    0.0    0.0    0.0
5   6    B    391   T    0.0  391.0    0.0
6   7    C    998   F    0.0    0.0    0.0
7   8    C    565   T    0.0    0.0  565.0
8   9    C    128   T    0.0    0.0  128.0
```

Comment: This answered the second question of automating the naming of the columns, but the sum should be based on the ´Ind´ variable. For example, in A we only sum the values where the Ind is 'T'. May I need to edit my question to make clearer!

Comment: I guess I can achieve this just by adding the ´Ind´ in the `groupby ` fucntion like this:
   
 `DF['SUM']=DF.groupby(['Ind', 'ID', 'Shop'])['Sales'].transform('sum')`

Comment: I can simply add this `DF.ix[DF.Ind==0,'SUM'] = 0`.
@Wen: please edit your answer accordingly so that I accept it, I have also edited my question for a clearer knowledge share

Comment: owise, The answer had been edited. I think the DF.Ind==0 should be  DF.Ind=='F' based on your original question. Glad to help ~

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps want something like this?

```
Shop = ["A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"]
Sales = [554, 678, 546, 896, 426, 319, 998, 565, 128]
List = ["A", "B", "C"]
A = []
B = []
C = []
Ticker = 0
for x in range(len(Sales)):
    if Shop[Ticker] == "A":
        A.append(Sales[Ticker])
    elif Shop[Ticker] == "B":
        B.append(Sales[Ticker])
    else:
        C.append(Sales[Ticker])
    Ticker += 1
print(sum(A), sum(B), sum(C))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['ID','Shop']).Sales.sum().unstack(fill_value = 0).reset_index(), on = 'ID').rename(columns = {'A': 'A_sum', 'B': 'B_sum', 'C': 'C_sum'})


    ID  Shop    Sales   Ind A_sum   B_sum   C_sum
0   1   A       554     T   554     0       0
1   2   B       678     F   0       678     0
2   3   A       546     T   546     0       0
3   4   A       896     T   896     0       0
4   5   B       426     F   0       426     0
5   6   B       391     T   0       391     0
6   7   C       998     F   0       0       998
7   8   C       565     T   0       0       565
8   9   C       128     T   0       0       128
```

Another solution without merge or concat and much faster gives the same result

```
df[['ID','A_sum', 'B_sum', 'C_sum']] = df.groupby(['ID','Shop']).Sales.sum().unstack(fill_value = 0).reset_index()
```